# I'm trying to install Wine 6.0 on Ubuntu but it just won't let me

Tags: apt, wine

I've tried reinstalling, installing, and I've just been stuck with WINE 5.0 for quite a while and I don't know why! I'm a new linux user so I don't really understand how I can fix this!
Here's what I get after adding the key to my apt and attempting to install.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 6.0.1~hirsute-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Package is from WineHQ, I'm following these instructions exactly: https://www.winehq.org/announce/6.0.1

My Ubuntu Version is 20.04

All current repositories installed to my PC

```
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210209.1)]/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
/etc/apt/sources.list:# newer versions of the distribution.
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
/etc/apt/sources.list:## distribution.
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
/etc/apt/sources.list:## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
/etc/apt/sources.list:## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
/etc/apt/sources.list:## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
/etc/apt/sources.list:## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
/etc/apt/sources.list:## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
/etc/apt/sources.list:## security team.
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
/etc/apt/sources.list:## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
/etc/apt/sources.list:## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
/etc/apt/sources.list:## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
/etc/apt/sources.list:## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
/etc/apt/sources.list:## 'partner' repository.
/etc/apt/sources.list:## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
/etc/apt/sources.list:## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:
/etc/apt/sources.list:# This system was installed using small removable media
/etc/apt/sources.list:# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
/etc/apt/sources.list:# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
/etc/apt/sources.list:# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
/etc/apt/sources.list:# see the sources.list(5) manual.
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ hirsute main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ hirsute main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ groovy main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ groovy main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/boltgolt-ubuntu-howdy-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/boltgolt/howdy/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/boltgolt-ubuntu-howdy-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/boltgolt/howdy/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/boltgolt-ubuntu-howdy-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/boltgolt/howdy/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/boltgolt-ubuntu-howdy-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/boltgolt/howdy/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save:### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save:# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/lutris-team-ubuntu-lutris-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list:deb https://repo.nordvpn.com//deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nordvpn.list.save:deb https://repo.nordvpn.com//deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openrazer-ubuntu-stable-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openrazer/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openrazer-ubuntu-stable-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/openrazer/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openrazer-ubuntu-stable-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/openrazer/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openrazer-ubuntu-stable-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/openrazer/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/polychromatic-ubuntu-stable-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/polychromatic/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/polychromatic-ubuntu-stable-focal.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/polychromatic/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/polychromatic-ubuntu-stable-focal.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/polychromatic/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/polychromatic-ubuntu-stable-focal.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/polychromatic/stable/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/windscribe-repo.list:deb https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/windscribe-repo.list.save:deb https://repo.windscribe.com/ubuntu bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine.list:deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/wine-obs.list:deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_19.04 ./
```

Comment: You question lacks all of its context. Where is coming the package from, what are your repositories (all of them), what is your Ubuntu version etc.

Comment: Sorry! Updated it!

Comment: Why do you have so many repositories from multiple distributions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pruning all the comments and other repositories, you have this:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ hirsute main
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ groovy main
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
```

Since you're using the Ubuntu 20.04 aka *focal* release, keep only the entry meant for it (and once rather than twice):

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
```

And remove the others from your list. Repositories providing packages for releases newer than yours: *groovy* and *hirsute* will cause compatibility conflicts, probably because they depend on package versions not yet available on *focal*.

Comment: Here's what I get when I put "Echo" in front the Deb (it says deb command isnt a thing) `jo
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main` Just that, nothing else my command was `echo deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main`

Comment: I'm really puzzled by your comment. My answer is telling you to edit the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` you gave in your question and add a comment character `#` for the 3 lines that should be disabled like the many other commented out lines by the character `#` already present in this file, or simply to remove these lines. Why are you talking about `jo` (???) or `echo`? Did I ever write `jo` or `echo` anywhere?

Comment: It worked! Sorry for all the inconviniece and how puzzling that was, thanks for the help :D

Comment: Hem, if you want to thank me, you should mark this answer as the accepted solution.

Comment: It was a comment tho... I can't mark it D:

Comment: @JosTheDude: complete nonsense. The comment was to clear up your confuseion regardding the answer - which was clearly demostrated by your first comment on the answer - whiich forced A.B to repeat the anwser This is why there are comments. You should mark the answer as  accepted if for no other reason then for sake of other people who may be looking for a similar answer.